# Laravel 5.4 artisan serve htaccess / and Routes::get for existing folders at /public

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.4

I'm still trying things with Laravel 5.4.
however running

```
php artisan server
```

is not taking .htaccess file in /public into consideration, no matter what i edit in there it's still not processing it, the artisan serve runs at 127.0.0.1:8000

--- i reached this issue cuz i was looking for one other thing which is:

i wanted to have a route::get for the /images folder which is already located at /public, removing -d from htaccess conditions should solve this normally, thus making apache redirect requests even from folders to index.php,

so while testing locally using php artisan serve i noticed that changes or even clearing the htaccess file does not change the behavior of laravel.

Thank you for your time.

**[note]**
htaccess works if i run laravel from apache, or anything but php artisan serve. so my question is only about the serve command and it's behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP has a basic web server feature. this server feature is what is used when you run `php artisan serve`. `.htaccess` is an Apache server feature *not* a PHP feature.

PHP is not built to be a full blown web server so it doesn't have all the configuration options you would find on say Apache or Nginx

Comment: so basically there is no htaccess rules in there or a way to change the behavior of accessing existing folders on the server, example /css /js /images... in the /public folder ?

Comment: @emad basicaly what `php artisan serve` is basically this command `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/`.

`-S` tells it the hostname and port to use and `-t` is the Document root.

If you request a url to a file that exists, you would get the file. if you request a url to a file that does not exist, php redirects the request to the index.php file in that directory

Answer (score 1):

you need to define it in the artisan config file!

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

As explained on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead (homestead is vagrant+)

> Laravel Homestead is an official, pre-packaged Vagrant box that
>   provides you a wonderful development environment without requiring you
>   to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your
>   local machine. No more worrying about messing up your operating
>   system! Vagrant boxes are completely disposable. If something goes
>   wrong, you can destroy and re-create the box in minutes!

Comment: thank you but laravel works just fine with serve, (i'm running on windows + phpstorm, not a virtual boxes), my question is about the behavior of artisan serve since i'm not going to be running it thru wamp all the time, i prefer the serve command for performance reasons, however the htaccess file at /public seems to be neglected by the serve command.

Comment: Hi I would like to clarify: 1) The answer is about vagrant 2) PHPStorm is using virtualbox, as PHPStorm itself is not virtual machine software 3) Because of this, PHPStorm still needs a correct setup vagrant config file.