# Laravel how to block access to all .txt files in directory with .htaccess file

Tags: php, laravel

In my project-name\public\user-note folder there are .txt files that I don't want others to access and I added a .htaccess file with the content:

```
<filesmatch "\.(ini|psd|log|sh|txt)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</filesmatch>
```

And one more thing is that when I access `http://<ip>:8000/.htaccess`, it shows all the contents of the .htaccess file in the project-name\public folder

[Image does not block .txt  file access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgQVc.png)

[.htaccess file images can be viewed by visitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPKcx.png)

Comment: Your local dev machine security will be necessarily lax. Are you getting these same outcomes on your public server? I ask because this isnt a programming problem but would deal with the webserver setup that may or may not be in your control, if public (e.g. a hosting provider)?

Comment: so... a curious question, did you by any chance.. starts laravel using `php artisan serve`? see [this qa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432874).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11729748/8577321 this is what you need . duplicated question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deny access to a file in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

<Files "log.txt">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```